# Refraction planes texture view vector mapped

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

### Refraction planes texture view vector mapped?

My blend to test: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1a9yqhqfis5wlrx/mIN5.blend

[image]
Principle is: texture is fixed, whenever you move object texture will not move together with object.

[image]

And I'm want to do this with refraction texture. Refraction as fixed background texture, I'm not sure, but it's called view viewport. Important! Plane must have 3D scene objects view inside.

And finally result have to look something like this:
[image]

How to do 3D perspective on only 1 plate with fixed texture?

Any demo?

---

Please, suggest me any possibility solution.

Comment: Can you place an image to help others to understand your question?  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: reformulate your question, your images do not help you understand what you want, viewport view is any view that has a camera showing the player the scenario, it is not understood what you want to do